# Program looping two times (printing statement twice)

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm trying to make a simple program for which the user is supposed to enter character 'a'. It is supposed to loop until 'a' is input. I have one statement printed if there is no input which works correctly. There is another statement if an incorrect letter or number is input, but the problem is that this causes the program to loop more than once and it prints the statements multiple times. Any help in fixing this is appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char input;
    int i, len,num;
    len = 1;

    do
    {
        puts("Please enter alphabet 'a': ");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            if(isalpha(input)==0)
            {
                printf("Please input something.\n");
                continue;
            }
            if(input == 'A' || input == 'a')
            {
                printf("Congratulations! You successfully input letter 'a'.");
                return(0);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("That's not letter 'a'.");
            }
        }
    }
    while(1);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop? Also, you should check the return value of `scanf()` before assuming the variable holds something valid.

Comment: The `for` loop is sure to loop once. Remove it. It is unecessary. Plus, you'll have an infinite loop when you don't enter an alphabet. And use `while(1)` instead of `do...while(1);`. You also forgot to include `ctype.h`. Also, using `return(0);` at the end of `main` is better. You have an unused variable `num` in your code too.

Comment: Hi. I tried getting rid of the for loop and running the program but it still didn't fix the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after entering the character, you press newline and this is send to the input buffer. Now the next time `scanf()` is called, it reads the value from the buffer which is `'\n'` and `scanf()` thus stores this to `input`. Now this can be easily solved by the method pointed by @Gopi, but there is a better way. This is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char input,ch;

    do
    {
        puts("Please enter alphabet 'a': ");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        while( input!='\n' && (ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!= EOF);   // look here

            if(isalpha(input)==0)
            {
                printf("Please input something.\n");
                continue;
            }
            if(input == 'A' || input == 'a')
            {
                printf("Congratulations! You successfully input letter 'a'.");
                return(0);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("That's not letter 'a'.");
            }

    }
    while(1);
}
```

Now with the statement `while((ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch!= EOF);`, all the characters like `'\n'` are just flushed and not stored to `input` and thus solves the problem.

Also note that you don't need the for loop here, its useless for this code ( unless this is not your original code and there are other parts in it ).

Comment: This takes two blank values (pressing enter twice) for the program to output "Please enter something", but it is definitely a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: @grammer , fixed that problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a newline character in the buffer after the first input which is not flushed and that is being picked up by the `%c` in the second iteration.

Change your `scanf()` to

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
```

Note the space before `%c` which gobbles the newline character

Comment: This solution works, but the problem is that if the user just presses enter without any input, it doesn't output  "Please input something".

Comment: @grammer Your code is really messed up. Why do you need a for loop within while loop.. So basically newline character is not a alphabet so you don't see anything ..